# Read/Write windows registry on 64bit Win 7 using JAVA with JNA

Tags: java

I'm trying to read/write windows registry on 64bit Win7 using JAVA.

Firstly, I tried JDK [`java.util.prefs.Preferences` and its reflection usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java). That is a good solution but it only supports reading/writing REG_SZ type (string) value.

Unfortunately, I need to read/write REG_BINARY, so give it up.

Secondly, I tried [JNI Registry](http://www.trustice.com/java/jnireg/). Reading is ok, but writing usually fails because writing HKLM needs administrator rights. I don't know how to get administrator rights in JAVA.

Finally, I tried JNA (Java Native Access) an excellent project for working with native libraries and has support for the Windows registry in the platform library (platform.jar) through `Advapi32Util` and `Advapi32`. It's very good and simple to use. And writing registry needs no administrator rights.

But how can I read/write 32bit Registry (under WOW6432Node node) in a 64bit JVM on Win7?

By default, 64bit nodes are read/written in 64bit JVMs, and 32bit nodes in 32bit JVMs.

But in a 64bit JVM, I want to read/write 32bit nodes(for example, `HKLM->SOFTWARE->Wow6432Node->ODBC`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer:
Using 64 bit Windows:

1. A 32 bit JVM, visiting `HKLM->SOFTWARE->ODBC` will be redirected to `HKLM->SOFTWARE->Wow6432Node->ODBC`
2. A 64 bit JVM, visiting `HKLM->SOFTWARE->ODBC` will be `HKLM->SOFTWARE->ODBC` (which is 64bit registry).
3. A 32 or 64bit JVM, visiting `HKLM->SOFTWARE->Wow6432Node->ODBC` is allowed. (but in C++, win32 exe can't visit `HKLM->SOFTWARE->Wow6432Node->ODBC` directly, should visit `HKLM->SOFTWARE->ODBC` with wow64 flag).

Answer (score 1):

JNA 5 adds new methods to Advapi32Util which allows you to specify the samDesiredFlags including KEY_WOW64_32KEY or KEY_WOW64_64KEY.

PR here:
https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/pull/1001

Registry security and access docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights

> KEY_WOW64_32KEY (0x0200)
>   Indicates that an application on 64-bit Windows should operate on the 32-bit registry view. This flag is ignored by 32-bit Windows. For more information, see Accessing an Alternate Registry View.
>   This flag must be combined using the OR operator with the other flags in this table that either query or access registry values.
>   Windows 2000: This flag is not supported.
>
> KEY_WOW64_64KEY (0x0100)
>   Indicates that an application on 64-bit Windows should operate on the 64-bit registry view. This flag is ignored by 32-bit Windows. For more information, see Accessing an Alternate Registry View.
>   This flag must be combined using the OR operator with the other flags in this table that either query or access registry values.
>   Windows 2000: This flag is not supported.

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked by using this new parameter and switching from 32 to 64 bits. In java these constants are found in WinNT class : WinNT.KEY_WOW64_32KEY and WinNT.KEY_WOW64_64KEY