# Advapi32util registrykeyexists() in java code returns false even if key is present in the windows registry

Tags: java, registry

I am new to **registrykeyexists(root,key)** method of Advapi32util which checks whether registry key "**key**"(key that is passed to registrykeyexists) is present in windows registry under the root.

Root that i am passing is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE".
Key is something that looks like "SOFTWARE\ABC\ABC DB"

And I see that this key is present in window's registry. ( by running "regedit" via cmd)

Below is the code snippet which does this work.

```
public static String getRegistryData(WinReg.HKEY root, String key, String value) {

        System.out.println("Registry key exists status:" + Advapi32Util.registryKeyExists(root, key));

        if (Advapi32Util.registryKeyExists(root, key)) {
            String retVal = Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(root, key, value);
            return retVal;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So,here when I debug, Advapi32Util.registryKeyExists(root, key) returns false.

Can anyone help me on this?? I would be grateful !!

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is some months old, but I had the same question as you.. And I hope this answer can help more people.

This can be a bit confusing, but the namings for these items work like this:
[image]

The Keys would be like the Path, and the Values would be each value inside a Key. After understanding it, it should be easier to do the coding. The method *Advapi32Util.registryKeyExists* looks for Keys (in other words, paths), so it won't help you.

If you want to verify if the value *Counter* exists in the key  *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009* for example, you should use this method:

```
boolean keyExists = Advapi32Util.registryValueExists(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Perflib\\009", "Counter");
```

In your case, your method would be:

```
public static String getRegistryData(WinReg.HKEY root, String key, String value) {

    System.out.println("Registry key exists status:" + Advapi32Util.registryValueExists(root, key, value));

    if (Advapi32Util.registryValueExists(root, key, value)) {
        String retVal = Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(root, key, value);
        return retVal;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can take a look in their GitHub project if you are curious in how they implemented it: [Advapi32Util - JNA GitHub Project](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.java)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I guess it applies to what you witnessed there.
Since version 5, JNA added a parameter into their registry navigation methods that allow to switch from 32 to 64 registry "realms"

Look at that excellent answer from @CamW
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57051855/2143734